printing integers twice in one printf statement in a c program
So the problem I am having is that one of the random number integers is printing twice but only in the second printf statement in the program at the bottom. This code is also just a test for the game Rack-O which I am recreating in c. So if I or someone can figure out how to make this code work the full game will also work. NOTE: if my code looks bad its because I am slightly new to coding.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
    int game = 1;
    srand(time(0));
    const int MIN = 1;
    const int MAX = 60;
    int starting_numbers10 = (rand() % MAX) + MIN;
    int starting_numbers9 = (rand() % MAX) + MIN;
    int sum1;
    int sum2;

    while(game == 1){
        int gamecards = (rand() % MAX) + MIN;
        int start;

        printf("%d\n", gamecards);
        printf("do you want to change numbers 1 or 2 : ");
        scanf("%d", &start);

        if(start == 1){
            sum1 = starting_numbers10 - starting_numbers10 + gamecards;
        }
        else if(start == 2){
            sum2 = starting_numbers9 - starting_numbers9 + gamecards;
        }
        printf("1 new sum: %d\n", sum1);
        printf("2 new sum: %d", sum2); // <-- example of what it prints (523) 52 being its own integer and 3 being the integer that sum1 can become if you select to change sum1

    }
}

I have tried many different combinations of the code over the past few days spending hours at a time trying to fix the problem but I never get the problem solved. Most likely I am just too inexperienced to know what to do but I haven't given up trying. But I expect that it shows the 2 random integers and not 3. I also expect the solution to be simple as well.

Try adding \n to the end of the format string.

Is this version of your code doing the right thing or no?

It looks like you print either sum1 or sum2 (or both) when it is uninitialized on the first iteration.  If you type 3 or anything other than 1 or 2, both will be uninitialized.  You should check the result from scanf() — it's also a good idea to print out what the program read to make sure it got what you thought it would get.

The expression sum1 = starting_numbers10 - starting_numbers10 + gamecards; looks as if it evaluates the same as sum1 = gamecards;, and similarly with the sum2 expression.  Is that deliberate?  What's the purpose?

UPDATE: First I want to thank Greg spears and dbush because the code is actually working fine I just never added the newline so it kept printing the integer and the new integer next to each other so I would have never noticed so thank you!

Also to answer your question Jonathan Leffler I am creating a game called Rack-o here is a link to the rules of the game https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1khxVK2Evks the point of the starting numbers is that those are the numbers you get at the beginning which then your supposed to replace by getting new cards in an ascending order which if all cards are in an ascending order you win.

But I will admit you can just have sum1 = gamecards; as it does achieve the same goal and I am currently using that in the full game actually.


sum1 and sum2 isn't being initialized when first used.
The result when you try to access value of uninitialized variable is Undefined.
"Behavior is undefined" means anything can legally be happened, like getting weird value, crash of your program or even explosion of your physical machine.
Initialize them to 0 to make it properly work.
printf("2 new sum: %d", sum2); has no newline character at the end of its format string. This would cause output of printf("%d\n", gamecards); to be mixed with it.


The usual consequence of invoking undefined behavior are nasal demons.

I was not developed enough to use computer at the time Usenet was a thing. I thought about Divide by zero AVR explosion video, but now I know it was just overvoltage that caused the explosion.

Neither me, knowing the history avoids repeating errors. :-D
